# How to fix VS Code unable to create a strapi app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, version, strapi

I'm Having an issue that ruins my entire development plans, And I don't think I'm even the problem!

There is an headless CMS program (open source) called [Strapi](https://%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://strapi.io), If you know the program then good, If not, Your more than welcome to try and tell me if you can help me with this problem.

I'm having trouble creating a Strapi app in VSCode.

The error that I'm receiving is:

```
You are running Node.js 18.4.0
Strapi requires Node.js >=14.19.1 <=16.x.x
Please make sure to use the right version of Node.
```

But, The fault isn't on me, I have 16.17.0 version of node installed, and without a trace of the 18.4 version specified on the error code.

I tried uninstalling node, Changing the dependencies in the launch.json file, Nothing worked!

Answer (score 0):

So I Found the solution, the problem was with the version, the recommended 16.17.0 version of node not working with strapi, the 16.15.0 works actually.